# PowerPoint Theme Name is "Blank"

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, themes, templates, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have added 2 Custom Colours to an Office Theme called TMRColours.thmx.  The goal is to have this theme used by default in Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Outlook, making the 2 colours available in all new documents.

I have largely succeeded, but one small issue remains with PowerPoint, and I hope someone can shed some light.

Successful behaviour in the other programs:  In Word, Excel and Outlook, you can go to where you choose which Theme to use, and you can see that the theme 'TMRColours' is selected.

Unexpected behaviour in PowerPoint:  In PowerPoint, yes, my custom colours are present.  However, when you look under Design, and hover over the theme that is selected, it reads "Blank: used by all slides".  I would have expected "TMRColours: used by all slides". It's not that an incorrect theme is selected, but that it is referred to as Blank, rather than TMRColours.  In every other respect, it *is* the correct TMRColours theme.  This also shows at the bottom, in the PowerPoint status bar - Slide 1 of 1 | "Blank"

Anyway, this may be normal, and may be inevitable since the name of the PowerPoint template where the default Theme to use is set has to be Blank.potx, but it seems a bit unprofessional.  So I wanted to see if anyone knew more about this, and how the visible name might be affected.

Thanks in advance,
Sandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but maybe Blank is the name of the Slide Master?

Try to go to view > Master View. Then select the first slide (the slide master) and chose Slide Master > Rename

Comment: You got it!!  Sorry, I haven't been back to this client since last week, but tried it today.  Brilliant - thank you so much!